# Scrapy tutorial error: "Running 'Scrapy Crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported"

Tags: python, scrapy

Windows 10, Command Line Terminal, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

New to Python & following tutorial instructions here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

On the step where I run my first crawl, I get the following error...I've only created one file quotes_spider.py as the tutorial suggests. I've also tried changing the directory to `c:\Anaconda\projects\tutorial\startproject` and `c:\Anaconda\projects\tutorial\startproject\spiders` but get the same error.

```
c:\Anaconda\projects\tutorial>c:\Anaconda\Scripts\scrapy.exe -scrapy crawl quotes  

2017-11-09 16:08:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: startproject)
2017-11-09 16:08:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'startproject', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'startproject.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['startproject.spiders']}
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

scrapy: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

Comment: what's `-scrapy`?

Comment: run it without  -scrapy, just pass the parameters `crawl quotes` to the scrapy executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong

**`....scrapy.exe -scrapy crawl quotes`**

### What it should be

**`....scrapy.exe crawl quotes`**

### Why

> This is scrapy's all available commands, there is no `-scrapy` option:
>   [image]

### Suggestions

[Scrapy Official Tutorial PDF Version](https://d.pr/free/f/gYG73Y)